# How to find the time difference between 2 date-times in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe

```
+-----+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+
|empId| lId|     date1|      time1 |  date2   |    time2   |
+-----+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 1234|1212|2018-04-20|21:40:29.077|2018-04-20|22:40:29.077|
| 1235|1212|2018-04-20|22:40:29.077|2018-04-21|00:40:29.077|
+-----+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Need to find the time difference between the 2 date-times(in minutes) for each empId and save as a new column. 
Required output :

```
    +-----+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
    |empId| lId|     date1|      time1 |  date2   |    time2   |TimeDiff |
    +-----+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
    | 1234|1212|2018-04-20|21:40:29.077|2018-04-20|22:40:29.077|60       |
    | 1235|1212|2018-04-20|22:40:29.077|2018-04-21|00:40:29.077|120      |
    +-----+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Do your dataframe have same column names?

Comment: Yes,  i joined 2 dataframes. I can change it if required.

Comment: I guess if you don't change before join you will get conflict. can you add the expected output too ?

Comment: added required output

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: I did the same with timestamp. But need to get the difference between 2 date-time with dates and times are in different column.

Comment: Is this time diff in minutes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `concat` `date` and `time` and convert it to `timestamp` and find the `difference` in minutes as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" //datetime format after concat

val newDF = df1.withColumn("TimeDiffInMinute",
  abs(unix_timestamp(concat_ws(" ", $"date1", $"time1"), format).cast("long")
  - (unix_timestamp(concat_ws(" ", $"date2", $"time2"), format)).cast("long") / 60D
)
```

`unix_timestamp` to convert the `datetime` to `timestamp`, Subtraction of `timestamp` results in `seconds` and divide by 60 results in `minutes`.

Output:

```
+-----+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
|empId| lId|     date1|       time1|     date2|       time2|dateTime1|
+-----+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
| 1234|1212|2018-04-20|21:40:29.077|2018-04-20|22:40:29.077|     60.0|
| 1235|1212|2018-04-20|22:40:29.077|2018-04-21|00:40:29.077|    120.0|
+-----+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
```

Hope this helped!